# What is the practical difference between these two SQL statements?

Tags: sql

In an exam I was asked to retrieve the name of the transporters never having transported a container based in Rotterdam. The correct answer was

```
select  Transporter.ID 
from    Transporter
where   Transporter.ID not in (
   select TransporterID
   from   Container
   inner join Transportation on Container.ID = Transportation.ContainerID
   where Container.City = 'Rotterdam')
```

and nevertheless the following was marked as a wrong answer:

```
select  Transporter.ID 
from    Transporter
where   Transporter.ID in (
   select TransporterID
   from   Container
   inner join Transportation on Container.ID = Transportation.ContainerID
   where Container.City <> 'Rotterdam')
```

Why don't both statements lead to the same result? What is the practical difference between `in ( ... where A <> B )` and `not in ( ... where A = B )`?

[Note that `Transportation` is in the center of the relational scheme, with all its prime attributs being foreign keys]

Comment: Query 2 will return Transporters that have delivered to Rotterdam and at least one more place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's build a simple table as example :

**Container**

```
TransporterID | City
 1            | 'Rotterdam'
 1            | 'Paris'
 2            | 'Rotterdam'
```

And then this query

```
SELECT TransporterID
FROM Container
WHERE Container.City <> 'Rotterdam'
```

This will result 1 (the row with paris)

Then, `WHERE Transporter.ID IN ( ...` statement will give wrong result (transporter 1 has been to 'Rotterdam')

Answer (score 1):

Besides what the other answers point out, take `NULL`s into consideration:

If `City` is `NULL` both queries would treat the comparison as `FALSE` in their `WHERE` clause...

Comment: it would treat actually them as _unknown_, not true or false.

Comment: The comparison would return `NULL`, and the `WHERE` clause would treat the `NULL` as "not true" resulting the same as `FALSE` would...

Answer (score 0):

You version is answering a slightly different question:  "What are the ids of transporters that have transported a container somewhere other than Rotterdam?".

As for the best answer, I would use `not exists` (which is material) and table aliases (more stylistic):

```
select t.ID 
from Transporter t
where not exists (select 1
                  from Container c join
                       Transportation tr
                       on c.ID = t.ContainerID
                  where tr.TransporterID = t.id and
                        c.City = 'Rotterdam'
                 );
```

`NOT IN` does not behave the way most people expect when any row in the subquery returns `NULL` (all rows are filtered out in that case).  `NOT EXISTS` has the expected behavior.

Comment: The information you added about `not exists` it's been useful, but I can't even upvote your answer.